# Where can I find an easy reference for http headers?

Tags: http, http-headers

I'm looking for a reference for all possible http request and response headers as part of the http specification. I want to know what is syntactically acceptable in terms header names and header values. I'm sure it's probably defined in the http specification, but it's a bit dense for me to read quickly. Any suggestions? And if the answer is to look at the http specification, what approach would you suggest in reading and understanding it quickly?

Thanks!

Comment: Good luck finding a reference for *"all possible http request and response headers"* as there is no defined limitation specified in RFC 2616. This means that anything following the allowed grammar rules is acceptable. `My-Zanzibar-Header: boom!` is perfectly valid. Common headers can be found in [Section 14](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14) of the spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best reference will be the actual [HTTP 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html). It's not difficult to understand once you get into it. At the very least, look through the table of contents to understand its structure, then you can jump straight into the sections that interest you. Sections reference one another, so sometimes you will need to jump to a different section (or another document) to understand what you are reading.

- *[Section 14, Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14),* explains the standard header fields.
- *[Section 4.2, Message Headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2),* specifies the format of a header.

  - To understand 4.2, you might need to refer to [section 2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2).

Look at these also:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields
- [The IANA registry of message headers](http://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-header-index.html) (contains headers used by other protocols, but it is easy to sort on HTTP)